# Send Receipt Manully Authorize.net

Tags: php, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am sending receipt to customer when  transaction is success via Authorize.net.  which is working fine.

Now there are few customer which need duplicate copy of receipt again. Can we send them via Authorize.net.

I am unable to find that functionality in Authorize.net.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Using Authorize.net's API and SDK you could call the [GetTransactionDetailsRequest](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php/blob/master/TransactionReporting/get-transaction-details.php) with the transId and pipe the results to your customer's email.

Or you could post the following XML to the appropriate API endpoint, for the sandbox, that would be https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api, parse the response and send out your custom email receipt with the appropriate details included:

```
<getTransactionDetailsRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
      <merchantAuthentication>
        <name>**Your API Login ID**</name>
        <transactionKey>**Your Transaction Key**</transactionKey>
      </merchantAuthentication>
      <transId>**The Transaction ID**</transId>
</getTransactionDetailsRequest>
```